# multiply 2 numbers that are bigger than maximum limit of long double

Tags: c++, c

How to multiply 2 numbers that are bigger than maximum limit i.e `1.89731e+4932` of `long double` using C++/C eg. `2.79654E+25678` and `3.89574e+35890`  ...

Comment: where's your attempt??

Comment: i can't figure out a way to do it..it's an assignment question and ineed a solution badly for it

Comment: assignments should be attempted...They are given out for a reason.

Comment: You're given numbers in scientific notation. Hint: you can use that.

Answer (score 2):

There're two possibilities (C# examples):

You can use BigInteger (it seems inefficient in your very case, but convenient with high precision numbers)

```
BigInteger a = 279654 * BigInteger.Pow(10, 25678 - 5); // <- 2.79654E25678 = 279654E25678 * 1E-5
BigInteger b = 389574 * BigInteger.Pow(10, 35890 - 5); // <- 3.89574E35890 = 389574E35890 * 1E-5
BigInteger result = a * b;
```

You can operate mantissas and exponentas separatedly:

```
Double mantissaA = 2.79654;
int exponentA = 25678;

Double mantissaB = 3.89574;
int exponentB = 35890;

Double mantissaResult = mantissaA * mantissaB;
int exponentResult = exponentA + exponentB;

// Let's adjust mantissaResult, it should be in [1..10) (10 is not included) range
if ((mantissaResult >= 10) || (mantissaResult <= -10)) { 
  mantissaResult /= 10.0 
  exponentResult += 1; 
}
else if (((mantissaResult < 1) && (mantissaResult > 0)) || ((mantissaResult > -1) && (mantissaResult < 0)))  {
  mantissaResult *= 10.0 
  exponentResult -= 1;  
}

// Let's output the result
String result = mantissaResult.ToString() + "E+" + exponentResult.ToString();
```

P.S. Often in case of multiplications it's more convenient use *logarithms* and additions:

```
A * B -> Log(A) + Log(B)
```

Comment: @harold: Thank you for a improvement; I've edited the code to add mantissa adjustment